# c# Reflection, how to get generic type class properties

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a Generic type `List<Shift>` where

```
public class Shift
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "dd-MMM-yyy '(hours)'")]
    public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "hh':'mm")]
    public TimeSpan TimeWorked { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to get schedule props with attributes using reflection

```
var props = typeof(List<ShiftDayItem>).GetProperties();
var ShiftProperty = props.Last();
```

But **ShiftProperty** contains no attributes, so I can't access Date or TimeWorked.
Is reflection not aware of these or is there another way for me to get those properties?
Thanks!

Comment: Shift property will be the last Property of List, then. Did you mean typeof(Shift).Get properties()?

Comment: annoying can't share a screenshot of debugger, but properties are null for this object :(

Comment: Could you explain the problem you are trying to solve with this? Reflection may not be the best solution for you. Also, your question is unclear: what is `ShiftDayItem`? What exact information are you trying to get?

Comment: *"Is reflection not aware of these"* - It is, but you're not looking for them in the right place. You're reflecting on the list type, and not the element type. Also, properties are not guaranteed to be returned in any particular order, so calling `.Last()` is a crapshoot. Even if it works now, it could still break at any point in the future without changing the source code. Best to search by some definitive aspect of the property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need more code:

```
Dim shifttprops= ShiftProperty.PropertyType.GetProperties()
For Each prop in shifttprops
   Dim attrs = prop.CustomAttributes
Next
```

Note the use of `CustomAttributes` instead of `Attributes`

Comment: You may be on the right track, although the question is unclear. But you should probably consider giving an example in C#

Answer (score 2):

I think you are misunderstanding what "Properties" are in c#.
Your `Shift` class has 2 properties: "Date" and "TimeWorked". To get info about these 2 properties you can simply write: `typeof(Shift).GetProperties()`. You are calling `typeof(List<ShiftDayItem>).GetProperties()` which will give you properties of List class: Count, Capacity, etc.. these are entirely unrelated.

Comment: I'm actually doing the type-check from another assembly that's not aware of Shift object. I'm doing the ckeck on generic typeof(T), wheere T was List<Shift> but was struggling to get the attributes for the shifts.
I only phrased the question this way for simplification purposes. Thanks though

Comment: If T is List<Shift>, you can get Shift by calling var elemType = typeof(T).GenericTypeArguments[0].
see answer of @AndrewToasterr

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to get attributes from `Shift` properties. To do this you need to get the generic parameter `T` from `List<T>`. To achive this you can do this

```cs
// Gets the generic type T from List<T>, in your case Shift
// Replace 'typeof(List<Shift>)' with your actual list
Type listType = typeof(List<Shift>).GenericTypeArguments[0];
```

To get all attributes from the type `Shift` you first need to get all the properites from which you can get the attributes.

```cs
// Gets all properties from the generic type T
PropertyInfo[] shiftProperties = listType.GetProperties();
```

Now that you have all the properties you can get the attributes

```cs
// Gets all Attributes from each property and puts them in one list (SelectMany)
IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes = shiftProperties.SelectMany(prop => prop.GetCustomAttributes());
```

You get `IEnumerable<Attribute>` from each property, which would result in `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Attribute>>` which is not what we want. We used the method `SelectMany` which takes each IEnumerable and flattens it into one.
When you put everything together you get this

```cs
// Gets the generic type T from List<T>, in your case Shift
// Replace 'typeof(List<Shift>)' with your actual list
Type listType = typeof(List<Shift>).GenericTypeArguments[0];

// Gets all properties from the generic type T
PropertyInfo[] shiftProperties = listType.GetProperties();

// Gets all Attributes from each property and puts them in one list (SelectMany)
IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes = shiftProperties.SelectMany(prop => prop.GetCustomAttributes());
```